# PHP Radio Button Inside echo

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

```
    echo    "<form class='custom'>";
foreach ($prices->item as $item){
      $ongkir = $item->value;
      $transfer = $total_jne * 1000;
      $transfer_rp = $transfer + $ongkir;
      $jne = $item->service;
      $checked = ($jne == $_POST['ongkir'])? ' checked="checked"' : '';
      echo  "<tr><td><label for='$item'>
      <input class='custom' name='ongkir' $checked type='radio' id='ongkir'> $jne</label></td>";
      echo  "<td>Rp. $ongkir</td>";
      echo  "<td>Rp. $transfer_rp</td></tr>";}
      echo  "</table><hr></form>" ;
    }
```

Hi Everybody, how do i post "checked" with value='$transfer_rp' to another php file with button? :(

Comment: you could help by explaining what $checked is a place holder for?

Comment: You need a `<form action="other-php-file.php">` tag, if you have none yet.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? 

Are you talking about submitting the form to another php file? - as mario said, you need to specify the file in form action.

Would you like to just get the $checked value while it is being changed and use that value to send to another php file? - you need to catch the radio button change event on the client side and use AJAX to communicate with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radio input will come as "true" or "false", not as the value of its name property, so try

`$checked = ($jne == 'ongkir' && isset($_POST['ongkir']) && $_POST['ongkir'] == "true" )? ' checked="checked"' : '';`

Or alternatively since this is ugly

```
$checked = '';
if( $jne == 'ongkir' && isset($_POST['ongkir']) && $_POST['ongkir'] == "true" ){
    $checked = 'checked="checked"';
}
```